# How to check if a url exists on my own website

Tags: 7, uri

I need to check if a url exists in a **module** that I am creating.  How should I go about doing this? I tried to use a **@get_headers()** function with php, but sadly that doesn't work. I am wondering if there is a built in drupal function that I can use?

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_valid_path/7 drupal_valid_path

Comment: I am using that function, but sadly it never returns false.

Comment: There is a comment: Unlike many other Drupal "path" functions, drupal_valid_path() considers absolute/external urls to be valid "paths". Did it help you?

Comment: You can also look here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what fixed it:

```
if (!drupal_valid_path($path)) {
  // Not a system URL.
  if (!drupal_lookup_path('source', $path))  {
    // Not a path alias.
    // $path does not exist.
  }
}
```

Where `$path` is a relative url.

[Source](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2013/03/05/drupal-7-check-if-a-path-exists/)